# Stick to Bottom a Relative Layout (inside Relative Layout inside a ScrollView)

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, sticky

I have a Scrollview, and Inside it a Relative Layout the Inside this Relative Layout another one (Which I want to be sticked to the bottom of the screen)

here's my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".WelcomeActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background_activity_gray"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <!-- A lot of views -->


        <View
            android:id="@+id/aw_separator1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/aw1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />


        <!-- Relative Layout to be sticked to the bottom -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/aw_separator1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/aw_button"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/aw_button"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons_style"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Looks like the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` doesn't work here.. How can I achieve this ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure.. is there really a need for the first `RelativeLayout`? Wouldn't `LinearLayout` suffice?

Comment: Thank you, I think so.. I'm using it for the `android:layout_below` directive especially

Comment: Now I'm really not sure why it doesn't work here, but try reading a article by Romain Guy http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/ I think it is what you're trying to achieve, maybe you'll notice some error

Comment: If you want have your inner `RelativeLayout` stay at the bottom of the screen, why are you putting it inside of your `ScrollView`?

Comment: @Yjay the view is full of content, so the `ScrollView` is mandatory. Then when the user scrolls he has to find sticked to the footer this `RelativeLayout`

Comment: have you tried that you set the height from your first RelativLayout to match_parent?

Comment: Okay I have pretty similar layout and I found only one difference I can't see that could be it, but try it anyways: edit your `@+id/aw_separator1` to have `android:layout_above="@+id/ThatStickedRElLayout"` and of course delete the `android:layout_below="@+id/aw_separator1"`

Comment: @KubaSpatny thank you ! It works, but it looks in big screens that the height of the `separator` becomes really big to push the `RelativeLayout` it to the bottom, even if the height is `1dp`. any idea ?

Comment: Short workaround would be to put another empty `View` there beneath the separator that could stretch instead of the separator

Comment: haha I like your way of thinking :D It works but I don't really understand why `android:layout_above="@+id/ThatStickedRElLayout"` made the `separator` stretch and then solved the problem ?